# google login and real time database android studio java

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to find errors in my code in android studio. I made an activity given by our professors, which is an activity where you must log in in google account using google authentication and it must be stored in a real time database. Both of them are already connected to firebase and I fixed some errors, but when I ran it it always crashes.

heres my code

```
package com.example.gactivity2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;
    private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity"; // Add this line

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth instance
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signIn);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> signIn());
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, handle error
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // Navigate to the next activity
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
                            finish(); // Finish current activity
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.gactivity2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProfileAdapter profileAdapter;
    private List<UserProfile> userProfileList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.profileRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        userProfileList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Retrieve current user's information
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String displayName = currentUser.getDisplayName();
            String email = currentUser.getEmail();

            // Check if display name and email are not null before adding them to the list
            if (displayName != null && email != null) {
                userProfileList.add(new UserProfile(displayName, email));
                // Notify adapter about data changes
                if (profileAdapter != null) {
                    profileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Display name or email is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        profileAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(this, userProfileList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(profileAdapter);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.gactivity2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class ProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileAdapter.ProfileViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<UserProfile> userProfileList;

    public ProfileAdapter(Context context, List<UserProfile> userProfileList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userProfileList = userProfileList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProfileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.profile_item, parent, false);
        return new ProfileViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfileViewHolder holder, int position) {
        UserProfile userProfile = userProfileList.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(userProfile.getName());
        holder.emailTextView.setText(userProfile.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userProfileList.size();
    }

    public static class ProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView emailTextView;

        public ProfileViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            emailTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.gactivity2;

public class UserProfile {

    private String name;
    private String email;

    public UserProfile(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
}
```

heres my code for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/signIn"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/profileRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

i checked my log cat and searched level:error and level:deb

I tried updating my manifest and gradle, updating the java classes.

Comment: When an Android app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: I checked my logcat i shows :'

Comment: Did you [search for that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+resolution+of%3A+Lcom%2Fgoogle%2Ffirebase%2Fappcheck%2Finterop%2FInternalAppCheckTokenProvider) yet? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293445/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-google-firebase-appch) seems to indicate it's a mismatch between the versions. It might be worth it to use the BoM to ensure all Firebase library versions are in sync: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.